# How to target a value or a label of a material-ui button instead of class?

Tags: reactjs

I have this btn component when clicked it runs a function, I want to be able to identify this btn since I have multi btns I used to check for class list in vanilla JavaScript using .classList.includes to achieve that and depending on the class name I would set the condition any similar thing to use here instead of checking for the class since mui has those weird classes ?
sure I can check for inner text, but my point here I need to understand how to leverage those other attributes that don't seem too obvious..

```js
// Function 
   const addItem = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.label);
    //if(e.target === somthing do this ) else ( do that)
  }
  // BTN 
  <GeneralButton onClick={addItem} value='somevalue' label='somelabel' text={'Add an item'} />
```

Comment: `onClick={(e) => addItem(e, 'this one is special')}`

Comment: You can use `data-` attrs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Function 
   const addItem = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.label);
    if(e.target.dataset.special) console.log('special')
    //if(e.target === somthing do this ) else ( do that)
  }
  // BTN 
  <GeneralButton onClick={addItem} value='somevalue' label='somelabel' data-special="true" text={'Add an item'} />
```